# Why am I unable to delete a Service Resource record?

Tags: field-service-lightning

I am trying to delete a Service Resource record but there is no delete button anywhere.  Whether I have the record selected, or click the drop down menu next to it, or look in the quick actions / buttons on the record detail page there is no way to delete this record.  I am a System Administrator in my org and my profile has absolute full access to the Service Resource object, including "Delete".

Why can't I delete these records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because service resources cannot be deleted. As shown in the [object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_serviceresource.htm), only the following operations are supported:

> create(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), search(), update(), upsert()

Additionally, the [description for the Active](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_resource_fields.htm&type=5) field also explains of this limitation:

> When selected, this option means that the resource can be assigned to work orders. For service tracking purposes, **resources can’t be deleted**, so deactivating a resource is the best way to send them into retirement. *(Emphasis added)*

Comment: Thank you for the response (and thank you for the very useful object reference link; I've been looking for something like this).  This is a bit frustrating as I created a test record in a hurry at one point thinking I was in the sandbox and now my shame is apparently forever immortalized.

Comment: Sort of an off topic followup; what is the purpose of supporting the getDeleted() operation when deletion is not allowed?

Comment: @MattEden getDeleted and getUpdated are the two methods of the [Replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_for_data_replication.htm). At the SOAP level, this is enumerated as a single flag, "replicateable." If this flag is true, both methods are supported, if false, neither are supported. You can't enable just one. So, even though some objects can't be deleted (like this one), SOAP clients have no way of knowing simply by checking the flag, so both must be supported. Call it "because of backwards compatibility."